# Retrofit image upload using Base64 in android

Tags: android, base64, gson, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to upload the image using retrofit in Base64 format.

To convert bitmap to Base64,

```
public static String convertImageToStringForServer(Bitmap imageBitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(imageBitmap != null) {
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I do not want to upload the image using Typedfile.

My request method is below,

```
        @Multipart
        @POST("/pingpong")
        void doPingpong(@Part ("access_token") TypedString accessToken,
        @Part("image") TypedString profileImage,
        @Part("pixels") TypedString doPingPong,Callback<pixelsPing> callback);
```

Base64 conversion is correct, but I am not getting the image on server. What am i doing wrong in the above?

Comment: do not use typed string and multipart if you don't want typedFile.Simply use post and pass your base 64 image as string.Also make changes in your API accordingly.

Comment: any update on this ? I have to use this as well,

Answer (score 7):

Post your Base64 string as a Field parameter of your request. Also use the FormUrlEncoded annotation, which adds "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

```
@POST("/upload")
@FormUrlEncoded
void upload(@Field("image") String base64, Callback<ResponseObject> callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Model class

```
public class MyModel {

@SerializedName("name")
String Name;

@SerializedName("image")
String Image;

@SerializedName("response")
String Response;

public MyModel(String name, String image, String response) {
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
    Response = response;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getResponse() {
    return Response;
}

public void setResponse(String response) {
    Response = response;
}
 }
```

---

Interface

```
public interface MyInterFace {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("Filename.php")
Call<MyModel> imgUp(@Field("name") String name, @Field("image") String image);
}
```

---

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText name;
ImageView imageView;
Button button, upload;
static final int IMG_REQ = 777;
Bitmap bitmap;``

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    upload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            upMy();
        }
    });


}

    public void upMy() {
    String Img = imageToString();
    String name3 = name.getText().toString();
    MyInterFace interFace = ApiClient.getApi().create(MyInterFace.class);
    Call<MyModel> call = interFace.imgUp(name3, Img);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyModel> call, Response<MyModel> response) {
            MyModel myModel = response.body();
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            upload.setEnabled(false);
            name.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myModel.getResponse(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

    private void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_REQ);
   }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == IMG_REQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri path = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setEnabled(false);
            upload.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

    private String imageToString() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imagByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imagByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
}
```

---

Apiclient

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = Your Base URL;
public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getApi() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="30dp"
tools:context="shuan.sam.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Choose"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button_upload"
    android:text="Upload"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```